# Datagrid binding not getting MVVM dataset updates

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a little problem with datagrid binding in an MVVM application. I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` but it doesn't work with datagrid. Every time I insert a record to database grid doesn't refresh and I have to restart app to see changes. Here is XML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="PlantsGrid" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Margin="5" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding PlantsCollection}" SelectionChanged="PlantsGrid_SelectionChanged" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Nazwa" Header="Nazwa" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LatName" Header="Nazwa łacińska" Width="*" Binding="{Binding LatinName}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.DataContext>
                <ViewModel:PlantViewModel/>
            </DataGrid.DataContext>
        </DataGrid>
```

And code-behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Plant> _plantsCollection;
public ObservableCollection<Plant> PlantsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _plantsCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _plantsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PlantsCollection");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code where you add the record.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the record to your database context you also need to add it to your collection in your viewmodel. If you just add the record to the db the property changed event will not fire because the db insert does not connect to that collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, are you adding records directly to the database?

A simple "refresh" button that clears local data and reload database data will work if you are trying to avoid restarting that application every time to show database updates.

But I'm guessing you want database updates make their way to your application.
You can google around but there is no magic bullet here.

If your database is being updated outside the scope of your application you'll have to implement a way to notify the application that data has changed.
 Then a way to resolve those changes, including what to do about conflicts.

Maybe this helps you start your journey.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not needed:
OnPropertyChanged("PlantsCollection");

ObservableCollection already does that.

You need either reload from database or insert the new record(after database sucess) into your collection.

If you are using MVVMLight or similar MVVM packages, goto following link:
https://github.com/ntierontime/Log4Net/blob/master/Log4Net/UI/MVVMLight/Shared/ViewModels/ViewModelLog.cs